# Convert wav to mp3 in node js

Tags: sox, aws-lambda

Is there any npn packages to convert a wav file to mp3 file in node js? I want to run this script in aws lambda function. I tried sox and sox-audio packages, but it is not supported in lambda. I googled ffmpeg, didn't find any convertion between wav to mp3.

**Does any one give a good convertion package in node js?**

```
console.log('New Lambda Call');

var async = require('async');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var SoxCommand = require('sox-audio');
var sox = require('sox');

var s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    //console.log('Reading event option : ', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    var src_bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var src_key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    var dest_bucket = "dmlambda";
    var desk_key = src_key;

    var params = {
        Bucket: src_bucket,
        Key: src_key
    };

    if (src_bucket == dest_bucket) {
        console.error("Destination bucket must not match source bucket.");
        return;
    }

    var typeMatch = src_key.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        console.error('unable to infer audio type for key ' + src_key);
        return;
    }

    console.log()

    var audioType = typeMatch[1];
    if (audioType != "wav") {
        console.log('skipping non wav audio ' + src_key);
        return;
    }

    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data){

        if (err) {

            console.log(err);

            var message = "Error getting object " + src_key + " from bucket " + src_bucket +
                ". Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.";
            console.log(message);

        } else {

            console.log('Audio Content type:', data.ContentType);

            fs.writeFile('./tmp/temp_'+src_key, data.Body, {encoding: null}, function(err){

                if(err){

                    console.log("download file write error"+ err);

                } else {

                    console.log('Added temp_'+src_key+' to queue');

                    var arr = src_key.split(".");
                    var filename = arr[0];

                    var command = SoxCommand()
                            .input('./tmp/temp_'+src_key)
                            .output('./tmp/'+filename+'.mp3')
                            .outputFileType('mp3')
                            .outputSampleRate(44100)
                            .outputBits(192 * 1024)
                            .outputChannels(2);

                    command.on('prepare', function(args) {

                        console.log('Preparing sox command with args ' + args.join(' '));

                    });

                    command.on('start', function(commandLine) {

                        console.log('Spawned sox with command ' + commandLine);

                    });

                    command.on('progress', function(progress) {

                        console.log('Processing progress: ', progress);

                    });

                    command.on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {

                        console.log('Cannot process audio: ' + err.message);
                        console.log('Sox Command Stdout: ', stdout);
                        console.log('Sox Command Stderr: ', stderr);

                    });

                    command.on('end', function() {

                        fs.unlink('./tmp/temp_'+src_key, function(err){

                            if(err){

                                console.log("delete error : ",err);

                            } else {

                                console.log('Moved temp_'+src_key);

                            }

                        });

                        console.log('Sox command succeeded!');

                        var stream = fs.createReadStream('./tmp/'+filename+'.mp3');

                        s3.putObject({
                            Bucket: dest_bucket,
                            Key: filename+'.mp3',
                            Body: stream
                          }, function(err, data){
                             if(err){

                                console.log("upload error : ",err);

                             } else {

                                fs.unlink('./tmp/'+filename+'.mp3', function(err){

                                    if(err){

                                        console.log("delete error : ",err);

                                    } else {

                                        console.log('Moved '+filename+'.mp3');

                                    }

                                 });

                            }

                         });

                    });

                    command.run();

                }  

            });

        }

    });

};
```

Lambda log is :

```
2015-08-13T05:39:21.845Z    vg7ewk1gk1bjvn30    New Lambda Call

START RequestId: a5ec9286-417d-11e5-9a79-310ba41a5a40

2015-08-13T05:39:21.990Z    a5ec9286-417d-11e5-9a79-310ba41a5a40    

2015-08-13T05:39:22.285Z    a5ec9286-417d-11e5-9a79-310ba41a5a40    Audio Content type: audio/x-wav

2015-08-13T05:39:22.320Z    a5ec9286-417d-11e5-9a79-310ba41a5a40    Added temp_RE4bc9f41b1738c6def250a58e32d473aa.wav to queue

2015-08-13T05:39:22.322Z    a5ec9286-417d-11e5-9a79-310ba41a5a40    Preparing sox command with args ./tmp/temp_RE4bc9f41b1738c6def250a58e32d473aa.wav -t mp3 -r 44100 -b 196608 -c 2 ./tmp/RE4bc9f41b1738c6def250a58e32d473aa.mp3

2015-08-13T05:39:22.366Z    a5ec9286-417d-11e5-9a79-310ba41a5a40    Cannot process audio: Cannot find sox

2015-08-13T05:39:22.366Z    a5ec9286-417d-11e5-9a79-310ba41a5a40    Sox Command Stdout: null

2015-08-13T05:39:22.366Z    a5ec9286-417d-11e5-9a79-310ba41a5a40    Sox Command Stderr: 

END RequestId: a5ec9286-417d-11e5-9a79-310ba41a5a40
Process exited before completing request
```

Comment: What do you mean `sox` is "not supported"? AFAIK, AWS Lambda lets you run your own executables. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 4):

The [sox npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sox) is just an interface to *the* [sox CLI](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

In the error log, it says `Cannot process audio: Cannot find sox`. It is because you do not have the actual sox CLI installed. Install it.

In order to include the sox CLI in Lambda, from [the AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/):

> Including your own executables is easy; just package them in the ZIP file you upload, and then reference them (including the relative path within the ZIP file you created) when you call them from Node.js or from other processes that you’ve previously started. Ensure that you include the following at the start of your function code:
>
> process.env[‘PATH’] = process.env[‘PATH’] + ‘:’ + process.env[‘LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT’]

To summarize, you want to:

1. download the sox CLI [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/),
2. include it in the zip you upload,
3. include the special `process.env ...` line at the top of your node file, and
4. run

Comment: How can this be installed in aws lambda?

Comment: @IjasAhamed: that `npm` command will just install the sox js interface, not the actual sox CLI. Take a look at the edit for specific instructions.

Comment: OK. I got it. Is there any packages for conversion

Comment: @IjasAhamed uh.. `sox`? I don't understand your question. Do you mean a package that doesn't use a separate non-js library?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using AWS. Why don't you use [elastic transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) for this instead of Lambda. The elastic transcoder is specifically for transcoding audio/video files.

You can even trigger it based on files being put into a s3 bucket.

Comment: I had to convert about 50 audios per minute. So elastic transcoder is too expensive.

Comment: If the number of audios or transcoding time ($$$) is not a problem. This tutorial explain how to convert to mp3 when files arrive to s3: https://hackernoon.com/youtube-to-mp3-using-s3-lambda-elastic-transcoder-df2c5903dea8